# Не запускается Apache

Tags: apache

До вчерашнего дня работал на Денвере - работало все нормально больше года, утром сажусь за комп - запускаю - а значек Апача в трее появился и тут же счез. Все старндартные методы из гугла (скайп, просмотр кто занимает порт 80, антивирь, файервол , переустановка, перегрузка сетевых настроек )- ничего не помогает. Бьюсь уже часов 6 над проблемой.
Что может быть? Кстати на другую Ось на этой же машине поставил Денвер - незапустился - а ось вообще голая - на ней ничего не стоит. Куда копать ?

Comment: Копать в сторону линя

Comment: Логи не пробовали глянуть? Обычно у Апача есть папочка logs куда он все складирует. Там ищите. Можете сюда скинуть, если не разберетесь в причине.

Comment: @mikillskegg линь безусловно лучшее решение, но, тем не менее, можно попробовать поставить апач, php и mysql "по нормальному". Если у вас уже есть опыт то это (если не брать во внимание время на скачивание всего необходимого) минут 15-20, не больше

Answer (score 1):

Если лень ставить apache, php и mysql, то поставь XAMPP или OpenServer это альтернатива того самого Denwer-а.

Answer (score 0):

Скачай OpenServer.

Answer (score 0):

Запусти Apache вручную или подредактируй  .ini файл (извини не знаю какой)